# Setting focus after opening dialog - Polymer (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, accessibility

How would one place focus on a `paper-input` contained within a `paper-dialog` at the point of it being opened?

I currently have this basic code as a proof of concept, but it won't have focus.

I have found that this works with `autofocus` written in the `paper-input` but I don't think this is an appropriate method.

**HTML**

```
<paper-dialog style="margin:0; padding: 0;" class="changePictureDialog" id="dialog" with-backdrop entry-animation="scale-up-animation" 
        exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
    <paper-input style="margin:20px" id="newInput" placeholder="placeholder"></paper-input>
    <paper-button id="button" on-click="focusInput">button</paper-button>
</paper-dialog>
```

**JS**

```
openDialog : function() {
    this.$.dialog.open();
    this.$.newInput.focus();
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

`this.$.newInput.focus();`

To:

`this.$.newInput.autofocus = true;`

Comment: Cool beans! I thought it would be simple. Thanks

Comment: This is simple. Haha